# Set href in attribute directive in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up a Bootstrap tab strip with Angular 2.  I have the tabs rendering in an `ngFor` but I'm getting template errors when I try to put the `#` infront of the `href` expression.  So this template compiles but isn't what I want:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li *ngFor="let aType of resourceTypes; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}"
      role="presentation">
    <a [attr.href]="aType.Name"
       [attr.aria-controls]="aType.Name"
       role="tab"
       data-toggle="tab">
      {{aType.Name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is `[attr.href]="#aType.Name"`
but that blows up.  What is the correct syntax to prepend the `#` in front of the expression in the attribute directive?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no need to prefix with `#`

In this code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li *ngFor="let aType of resourceTypes; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}"
      role="presentation">
    <a [attr.href]="aType.Name"
       [attr.aria-controls]="aType.Name"
       role="tab"
       data-toggle="tab">
      {{aType.Name}}
    </a>
  </li>
```

`aType` already refers to the `*ngFor` variable.

If you want to prefix a literal `#` you can use

```
[attr.href]="'#' + aType.Name"
```

There is also no need for `attr.` if the element actually has the property `href` which is the case with `<a>`.

Comment: Once difference when using `[attr.href]` vs `[href]` is that the former will not bind if the value is null- this came in handy for me, since I wanted the anchor to be disabled if a url property I was binding wasn't set.

Comment: it gives me link like this. "localhost:4200/mywebsite.com". How can I handle this ?

Comment: What's wrong with that? What is the expected value?

Answer (score 12):

Well you can bind it with string interpolation:

```
href = "#{{aType.Name}}"
```

(Note that the attribute used here is `href`, not `[attr.href]`.)

Comment: This doedsn't work for me: `<a [attr.href]="{{address}}">`

Comment: @chovy You shouldn't mix attribute and object binding. Just remove those curly brackets arround your `address`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use  `routerLink` instead of `href`? I think, this will work

```
<a routerLink="#{{ aType.Name }}">Name<a>
```