# Angular 2 download file from rest service

Tags: angular

I have Angular 2 client that download a file from rest service:

```
 downloadAPK(projectName: string): void {
    this.projectService.downloadAppFile(projectName).subscribe(blobContent => {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobContent);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = projectName + '.apk';
        a.click();
    });

}
```

The Client code:

```
<div class="subTitleStatus">Ready 
    <a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="downloadAPK(project.name)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i></a>
</div>
```

The Service code:

```
downloadAppFile(projectName: String): any {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl + "/downloadAppFile/" + projectName,
        {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .map(res => res.blob())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The problem is that the user does not have any indication that the download started until the client finish downloading the file.
i'm talking about huge files

how can i change the client code to show downloading percentage when the user click the download link until finish downloading?

Thanks

Comment: you would need to have an onClick event handler. Since you didn't give much code on the ui template or the actual event I can't give you much help.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: What's in the service? Is there some sort of variable that shows how much has been sent to the client and how big the file is?

Comment: the service code updated on my question, the files size about 30MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why are you not downloading the file with as a link?

**First solution(Download link)**:

you don't need to download via service, just load the link in a new tab and browser will download it (if you have the correct headers like attachment header from the server)

```
    <div class="subTitleStatus">Ready 
        <a style="cursor:pointer" [attr.href]="downloadAPK(project.name)" target="_blank">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and this the service

```
    downloadAppFile(projectName: String): any {
        return this._productUrl + "/downloadAppFile/" + projectName;
    }
```

**Second solution(Via JavaScript)**:
you have another solution, but need some changes in server side
please read [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)
and more specific to angular2
[Angular 2 HTTP Progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158928/angular-2-http-progress-bar)

**Third Solution(Via Javascript - indeterminate)**:

```
downloadAppFile(projectName: String, start: ()=>void, stop: ()=>void): any {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl + "/downloadAppFile/" + projectName,
        {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .do(start)
        .map(res => res.blob())
        .finally(stop)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and in your controller define stop and start

start can be something like:

```
() => { this.showSpinner = true }
```

and stop:

```
() => { this.showSpinner = false }
```

so the final controller is something like:

```
downloadAPK(projectName: string): void {
    showSpinner = false;
    start = () => { this.showSpinner = true }
    stop = () => { this.showSpinner = false }
    this.projectService.downloadAppFile(projectName, this.start, this.stop).subscribe(blobContent => {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobContent);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = projectName + '.apk';
        a.click();
    });

}
```

and in view just add a spinner and show/hide it based on `this.showSpinner` variable

if you don't send the file size from the server you cannot determine the downloaded percentage

**Updates**

the third solution added

the first solution is updated based on [Angular2 set href in attribute directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948504/angular2-set-href-in-attribute-directive)

in first solution there was a type and href changed to [attr.href]

Comment: I prefer not to change the server side,  href="downloadAPK(project.name)" does not work in Angular 2

Comment: what about the second solution, if the second one is not good for you because of server side changes, the only solution remains is indeterminate progress/spinner
you can start in "do" section of Observable HTTP call and stop it on compleated/finally section