# Routing in Angular 5 not working

Tags: angular5

In my page, I have two links, addUser and viewUser.
Now my requirement is on clicking addUser, the page should redirect to the addUser component replacing both the links.
How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code that you have tried so others can spot / correct your mistakes (if any). It's hard to say why is your routing not working without knowing what you have done so far?

Comment: WOuld be easier if you have showed an example

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948504/set-href-in-attribute-directive-in-angular) is a post wich explain very well how it works and maybe can give you some ideas